# Relation between onCreate and attachInfo

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

In an Android application's ContentProvider, is the attachInfo call guaranteed to be invoked by the system once onCreate has been invoked? Does this happen even if the onCreate call fails and returns false?

Comment: see https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/ContentProvider.java, find attachInfo method

Comment: Does attachInfo get called even when onCreate returns false?

Comment: if you see the sources i posted link to you will see that ContentProvider.this.onCreate() is called at the end of attachInfo method